# Give unique identifier to consecutive groupings

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify groups based on sequential numbers. For example, I have a dataframe that looks like this (simplified):

```
UID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
11
12
13
15
17
20
21
22
```

And I would like to add a column that identifies when there are groupings of consecutive numbers, for example, 1 to 7 are first consecutive , then they get 1 , the second consecutive set will get 2 etc .

```
UID Group
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
11  2
12  2
13  2
15  3
17  4
20  5
21  5
22  5
```

none of the existed code helped me to solved this issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R method that uses `diff`, a logical check, and `cumsum`:

```
cumsum(c(1, diff(df$UID) > 1))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 5
```

Adding this onto the data.frame, we get:

```
df$id <- cumsum(c(1, diff(df$UID) > 1))
df
   UID id
1    1  1
2    2  1
3    3  1
4    4  1
5    5  1
6    6  1
7    7  1
8   11  2
9   12  2
10  13  2
11  15  3
12  17  4
13  20  5
14  21  5
15  22  5
```

Or you can also use dplyr as follows :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ID=cumsum(c(1, diff(df$UID) > 1)))
#   UID ID
#1    1  1
#2    2  1
#3    3  1
#4    4  1
#5    5  1
#6    6  1
#7    7  1
#8   11  2
#9   12  2
#10  13  2
#11  15  3
#12  17  4
#13  20  5
#14  21  5
#15  22  5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also get the difference between the current row and the previous row using the `shift` function from `data.table`, get the cumulative sum of the logical vector and assign it to create the 'Group' column.  This will be faster.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Group := cumsum(UID- shift(UID, fill = UID[1])>1)+1]
df1
#    UID Group
# 1:   1     1
# 2:   2     1
# 3:   3     1
# 4:   4     1
# 5:   5     1
# 6:   6     1
# 7:   7     1
# 8:  11     2
# 9:  12     2
#10:  13     2
#11:  15     3
#12:  17     4
#13:  20     5
#14:  21     5
#15:  22     5
```